# Porting Haskell inversion counter to Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting, haskell

Here's relevant code from Haskell implementation of a routine that counts inversion in a list

```
mergeAndCount :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> (Int,[a])
mergeAndCount l@(x:xs) r@(y:ys) | x < y = let (inv, s) = mergeAndCount xs r in (inv, x:s)
                                | otherwise = let (inv, s) = mergeAndCount l ys in (inv + rest, y:s)
                                                where rest = length l
mergeAndCount l [] = (0, l)
mergeAndCount [] r = (0, r)
```

I've tried to write similar routine in Scala but it crashes with stack overflow (lazy sorting works, though). Here's the the non-working version:

```
  def mergeAndCount(l: Stream[Int], r: Stream[Int]) : (Long, Stream[Int]) = {
    (l, r) match {
      case (x#::xs, Empty) => (0, l)
      case (Empty, y#::ys) => (0, r)
      case (x#::xs, y#::ys) => if(x < y) {
        lazy val (i, s) = mergeAndCount(xs, r)
        (i, x#::s)
      } else {
        lazy val (i, s) = mergeAndCount(l, ys)
        (i + l.length, y#::s)
      }
    }
  }
```

Any ideas on how to make Scala version to behave like the Haskell one?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the `lazy` modifiers are going to deepen your stack (but only by a constant factor), and I'm not sure they're doing what you think they're doing, anyway.

Comment: I don't have scala at hand, but I think your pair being non-lazy spoils the gains from declaring `lazy val`. What you need is `mergeAndCount(...) : (=> Long, Stream[Int])` kind of thing.

Comment: @SassaNF I've tried using a `class LazyTuple[a,b](x: => a, y: => b)` but it didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trade heap for stack in a situation like this (where turning the recursive call into a tail call might be complicated) by using [trampolines](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/tail-call-elimination-in-scala-monads/):

```
import Stream.Empty
import scalaz.std.tuple._
import scalaz.syntax.bifunctor._
import scalaz.Free.Trampoline, scalaz.Trampoline._

def mergeAndCount(
  l: Stream[Int],
  r: Stream[Int]
): Trampoline[(Long, Stream[Int])] = (l, r) match {
  case (_ #:: _, Empty) => done((0, l))
  case (Empty, _ #:: _) => done((0, r))
  case (x #:: xs, y #:: _) if x < y => suspend(
    mergeAndCount(xs, r).map(_.rightMap(x #:: _))
  )
  case (_, y #:: ys) => suspend(
    mergeAndCount(l, ys).map(_.bimap(_ + l.length, y #:: _))
  )
}
```

Note that I'm using [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)'s implementation here, since [the standard library's](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.TailCalls%24) is currently missing some pieces (although that [will change soon](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2865)).

Now you can write e.g. the following:

```
mergeAndCount((1 to 20000).toStream, (2 to 20001).toStream).run
```

Where this would almost certainly blow the stack if we weren't trampolining the tail calls.

Comment: Thing is, the sorting routine works just fine and it is in fact lazy - taking first element of resulting stream is much faster than taking the last. As far as I understand, `Tuple` constructor forces the evaluation of it's arguments which leads to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'd leave this as a comment but unfortunately I don't have the reputation yet to do so...

Anyway, you're likely to run into stack overflow errors if you recurse before the last call in your function - in Scala only tail recursion is optimised not to use the stack. If you can move the recursive call to the last line of each case (which would mean abandoning the laziness) then you might get better results.